# Index problems with partition function in C

Tags: c, sorting, quicksort

I was attempting to create a partition function for a quicksort that I want to run on an array of a Struct that I created.
However, during runtime the indexes suddenly act weird and go crazy. (for example after a certain `bigger=bigger-1` call, `bigger` suddenly gets the value `0` for no apparent reason.

This is my code:

```
int partition(Student studentsArray[], int left, int right)
{
    Student tempArr[right+1 - left];
    int smaller = left; int bigger = right;
    for(int i =left; i<right;i++)
    {
        if(stringComperator(studentsArray[i].name,studentsArray[right].name)>0)
        {
            tempArr[bigger]=studentsArray[i];
            bigger=bigger-1;
        }
        else
        {
            tempArr[smaller]=studentsArray[i];
            smaller=smaller+1;
        }
    }
    tempArr[smaller]=studentsArray[right];
    for(int i=left;i<right-left+1;i++)
    {
        studentsArray[i]=tempArr[i];
    }
    return smaller;
}
```

**edit:** updated code: seems to work inside of the method, but it seems like studentsArray won't change it values outside of the function call.

```
void swap(Student* a, Student* b)
{
    Student temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int partition(Student studentsArray[], int left, int right)

{
    Student pivot = studentsArray[right];
    int i = left;
    for(int j = 0; j<right;j++)
    {
        if(stringComperator(studentsArray[j].name,pivot.name)<0)
        {
            swap(&studentsArray[i],&studentsArray[j]);
            i=i+1;
        }
    }
    swap(&studentsArray[i],&pivot);
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has **undefined behavior** in lines such as:

```
  tempArr[bigger]=studentsArray[i];
```

Your `tempArr` size is `right+1 - left`, and `bigger` starts as equals to `right`.
This means that when `left > 0`, you are out of bounds.

One of the many things that could happen in these cases, is overriding other automatic allocated variables, such as `bigger`.

---

Few ways to solve it include pedantic checking for sizes. But, imho, the straightforward way is to avoid creating `tempArr`, and update the values inplace.

Comment: Thanks Amit!
I see what I did wrong there, thanks for pointing it out.
How would you update the values inplace? mind elaborating?

Comment: @willhunting1337 I meant, I would have updated `studentsArray` directly, instead of setting the value in `tempArr` and copy them to `studentsArray` later. [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme) has pseudo code suggesting how to do partition inplace.

Comment: Amit, I changed my code, it seems to work inside the method block, but the array won't actually change. mind taking a look?